# Cannot see database after giving privileges through role

Tags: mysql, database, roles, privileges, sql-grant

Using a role, I wanted to grant controlled access to a database for the administrator of that database. I tried using these sequence of commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
CREATE ROLE 'sysadmin';
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO 'sysadmin';
GRANT 'sysadmin' TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

However, when I re-enter mysql with 'user' login and I do `SHOW DATABASES;` I cannot see `my_db` I created earlier and supposedly gave grant to access to `sysadmin` which `user` is. Why am I not able to see it and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a role to the user, but after re-connect, you are not activating this role and it is not enabled by default. Try executing `SET DEFAULT ROLE 'sysadmin' TO 'user'@'localhost';` You can read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-default-role.html